# constexpr differences between GCC and clang

Tags: c++, c++17

The following compiles in GCC 9 but not in clang 10 and I'm wondering which of the two compilers is standard conforming:

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
  static const T s;
  static const T v;
};

template<typename T>
constexpr const T A<T>::s = T(1);

template<typename T>
constexpr const T A<T>::v = A<T>::s;

int main(int, char**) {
  constexpr auto a = A<double>::v;
  return 0;
}
```

This is intended to be a minimal example of a bigger issue which is why the fields `s` and `v` are explicitly declared as `const` but are defined as `constexpr`, this is intentional.

Is GCC correct to compile that code or is clang correct to reject it?

Comment: You should post the error message that clang gives.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Here we go: [**Demo on Compiler Explorer**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/g8ehrM). ;-)

Comment: At first glance, I'm inclined to believe clang here, but there might be some rule that allows `v` to change its constexpr specification during template specialization... In any case, this looks super janky.

Comment: According to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization): "The compiler is **permitted** to initialize other static and thread-local objects using constant initialization, [...]". So they might very well be both standard-compliant here.

Answer (score 1):

Compilers are only required to treat `static const` variables of integral and enum types as `constexpr` if they are initialize with a constant expression. This made it possible to use them as array lengths before `constexpr` was added to the language.