# Are static member variables of templates defined or specialized?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

This relates to the following question: [constexpr differences between GCC and clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61606637/constexpr-differences-between-gcc-and-clang)

In the following spinet, is the last line a specialization, a definition, or both?

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
  static const T s;
};

template<typename T>
const T A<T>::s = T(1);
```

This seems like a definition to me, but the posted question being compiled successfully by gcc has me questioning my assumptions.

Comment: I am not a language lawyer but I would say that the last line is definition. Why? Because I associate template specialization with template where the type is being specified and, here, it is not the case. I guess the last line would simply pass 1 to constructor of whatever `T` type is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definition.

The following would be a specialization.

```
template <>
const int A<int>::s = 20;
```

Given the following program,

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct A {
  static const T s;
};

template <typename T>
const T A<T>::s = T(1);

template <>
const int A<int>::s = 20;

int main()
{
   double a = A<double>::s;
   double b = A<int>::s;

   std::cout << "a: " << a << std::endl;
   std::cout << "b: " << b << std::endl;
}
```

You should expect the output to be:

```
a: 1
b: 20
```

See it working at https://ideone.com/t7Hxk9

Comment: Glad to see I'm not going crazy. Thank you.

Comment: @Frank, you're welcome. Glad I was able to help you stay sane :)